# How can you pass a variable to an other function in Python and set value to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, reference

I would like to pass a variable to an other function and in that function change the value of it.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
class TestClass:
    _g_a: int
    _g_b: int

    def __init__(self):
        self._g_a = 0
        self._g_b = 0

    @property
    def g_a(self):
        return self._g_a

    @g_a.setter
    def g_a(self, value):
        self._g_a = value

    @property
    def g_b(self):
        return self._g_b

    @g_b.setter
    def g_b(self, value):
        self._g_b = value

    def run(self):
        self.do_something(self.g_a, True)
        self.do_something(self.g_b, False)
        self.print_it()

    def do_something(self, the_variable, change: bool):
        if change:
            the_variable = 1

    def print_it(self):
        print(self.g_a)
        print(self.g_b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestClass()
    t.run()
```

If I run the aboce code I got 0,0 as a result instead of 1,0.

In PHP there is a way to pass the reference but I don't know how to achive this in Python since I just started to work with it, and I would like to understand how can I achive such a task.

Thanks for your help!

David

**Edited:**

```
from typing import List


class TestClass:
    a: List
    b: List

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = [0]
        self.b = [0]

    def run(self):
        self.do_something(self.a, True)
        self.do_something(self.b, False)
        self.print_it()

    def do_something(self, the_variable, change: bool):
        if change:
            the_variable[0] = 1

    def print_it(self):
        print(self.a[0])
        print(self.b[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestClass()
    t.run()
```

Comment: Why use a class with `property`s and `setter`s to demonstrate the problem? This could've been done with 3-4 short lines of code. The rest just serves as noise.

Comment: @Axe319 thanks for the constructive comment!

Comment: It appears that the edited version is a solution. Is that correct? Do you understand how name binding works in python?

Comment: @Carl_M hey, yes now I have a better perspective to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within defineAList(), assign certain values into the list; then pass the new list back into main()

Answer (score -2):

#Method1-using return value inside another function
def fun1(a):
res = a + 1
return res
def fun2(c):
res = c * 2
return res
output = fun1(fun2(1))
print(output)
#Method 2: directly calling one function in the other
def function_1(n):
v = n * n
num = function_2(v)
return num
def function_2(a_number):
a_number = a_number * 2
return a_number
print(function_1(10))

Comment: (1) Fix the formatting. (2) This is probably not a useful answer to the question.